# using awk to make new file, results in issues using 1 specific column, can't figure out what is wrong

Tags: awk

Trying to use this file...

```
    MT      200610-1        100     2757
    MT      200610-10       100     6753
    MT      200610-100      100     15173
```

Want to make a new file that looks like this, using columns 1,2,and 4...

```
    chrMT   2756    2757    200610-1
    chrMT   6752    6753    200610-10
    chrMT   15172   15173   200610-100
```

If I only do the first three like this it works..

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=="\t";OFS=="\t"}{print "chr"$1,$4-1,$4}' test_ace_geno1.map
    chrMT 2756 2757
    chrMT 6752 6753
    chrMT 15172 15173
```

If I try to add in the 2nd column at the end, something weird happens...

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=="\t";OFS=="\t"}{print "chr"$1,$4-1,$4,$2}' test_ace_geno1.map
     200610-16 2757
     200610-10 6753
     200610-100 15173
```

If I do vim with set list it shows it to be a regular tab so I'm not sure what is happening here with that column that is messing the entire thing up.

```
    MT^I200610-1^I100^I2757$
    MT^I200610-10^I100^I6753$
    MT^I200610-100^I100^I15173$
```

Comment: Does your file have window's line endings?

Comment: to follow up what @fd0 said, see if `cat -e test_ace_geno1.map` shows something like `^M$` as line endings.. that seems the main problem.. and minor formatting issue with using `==` instead of `=` when assigning `FS OFS`

Comment: Yes, thank you it shows that '^M$' as the line endings.  (and I fixed the '=' with FS and OFS and that now gives me the "chrMT" back in output).  But the fourth column doesn't seem to work properly still.  How do I remove or go around the '^M$'?

Comment: Another way to check for DOS format if you're using `vim` is just look at the bottom (status) line at startup for `"filename" [dos] numL, numC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `dos` style line endings:

```
$ cat -e ip.txt 
    MT      200610-1        100     2757^M$
    MT      200610-10       100     6753 ^M$
    MT      200610-100      100     15173^M$

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=="\t";OFS=="\t"}{print "chr"$1,$4-1,$4}' ip.txt 
chrMT 2756 2757
chrMT 6752 6753
chrMT 15172 15173

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=="\t";OFS=="\t"}{print "chr"$1,$4-1,$4,$2}' ip.txt 
 200610-16 2757
chrMT 6752 6753 200610-10
 200610-100 15173
```

With `perl` to handle both `dos` style line ending and getting required output:

```
$ perl -lane 'print "chr$F[0]\t", $F[3]-1, "\t$F[3]\t$F[1]"' ip.txt 
chrMT   2756    2757    200610-1
chrMT   6752    6753    200610-10
chrMT   15172   15173   200610-100
```

With `awk`, change line ending to `unix` style first, with `dos2unix` if available or with `perl`

```
$ perl -i -pe 's|\r\n|\n|' ip.txt 
$ cat -e ip.txt 
    MT      200610-1        100     2757$
    MT      200610-10       100     6753 $
    MT      200610-100      100     15173$
```

and then

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print "chr"$1,$4-1,$4,$2}' ip.txt 
chrMT   2756    2757    200610-1
chrMT   6752    6753    200610-10
chrMT   15172   15173   200610-100
```

or, with `GNU awk`, set input record to handle dos-style line ending

```
gawk -v RS='\r\n' -v OFS='\t' '{print "chr"$1,$4-1,$4,$2}' ip.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Put everything in the `print` statement in the desired format, and do any necessary operation e.g. the subtraction `$NF - 1` too:

```
awk '{print "chr" $1, ($NF - 1), $NF, $2}' file.txt
```

You can obviously use `$4` instead of `$NF` here, but as the 4th field is the last one, both of them would point to the same field.

**Example:**

```
% awk '{print "chr" $1, ($NF - 1), $NF, $2}' file.txt 
chrMT 2756 2757 200610-1
chrMT 6752 6753 200610-10
chrMT 15172 15173 200610-100
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and still getting the same as last example I showed.  It's like something is inside the second column or fourth column causing issues.  But again if I use 'set list' in vim this is what I see...

Comment: MT^I200610-1^I100^I2757$
        MT^I200610-10^I100^I6753$
        MT^I200610-100^I100^I15173$