# Variable completely messes up echoed string

Tags: bash

I discovered this website called pwnedpasswords, where you can apparently check to see if your password's sha1 hash has been leaked somewhere. So I made a script to automate the process, here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -s -p "Input your password: " your_pw
echo
your_hash=$(printf "$your_pw"|sha1sum|tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'|head -c40)
hash_head=$(printf "$your_hash"|head -c5)
hash_tail=$(printf "$your_hash"|tail -c35)

pwned_count=$(curl https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/${hash_head} 2> /dev/null|grep "${hash_tail}"|awk -F ':' '{print $2}')
echo "Your password has been pwned ${your_pw} times"
echo "Your password has been pwned ${pwned_count} times"
```

And I used as a test password `1`, and this is the output:

```
[me@my_compuuter aaa8]$ ./was_your_password_pwned.sh
Input your password:
Your password has been pwned 1 times
 timesassword has been pwned 197972
```

Notice how when I `echo "Your password has been pwned ${your_pw} times"`
 it gives me the correct format ($your_pw is just the password itself), but when I `echo "Your password has been pwned ${pwned_count} times"` it gives me this weird format where it takes the `times` from the end and somehow overlaps it in the beginning... I have no clue what's going on...

Can somebody figure it out?

Comment: Next time when you see something like this, pipe the output to `od` or `cat -A`.

Comment: Dupe https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312446/using-awk-to-make-new-file-results-in-issues-using-1-specific-column-cant-fig and cross https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837875/awk-field-variable-e-g-1-creates-new-line-concatenation-issue (mine). bash can select characters without head or/and tail, and do case conversion without tr; awk can match like grep and do the CR removal; there are Qs on all of these.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The list returned by that site has lines terminated by `CR/LF`. A `CR` (`\r`) will move the caret/cursor to the beginning of the line:

```
printf 'good \r times'
 times
```

Comment: Wow thanks! I just added `|tr '\r' '\n'` to the end of the `pwned_count` variable and now it works properly, thanks!

Comment: @user323587, `tr -d '\r'` would be more common, it actually removes the carriage return. Changing it to a newline of course works in your case, too, since the command substitution removes all trailing newlines.

Comment: Note use of CRLF line endings is common in Internet protocols, and in particular is required for **content-type: text/plain** _in MIME_ (email, or news), see [rfc2046 section 4.1.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046#section-4.1). It not clear all MIME requirements should (or sometimes can) carry over to HTTP, but it is best to assume they do when there is no statement or clear evidence otherwise.